# Remove DIV's innerHTML until a <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's say I have a `div`, as the following:

```
<div id="mainDIV">Area to remove <p>Area to not remove</p></div>
```

I want to remove the div's content/innerHTML until the `p` tag.
I tried to remove it by the following:

```
document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML = ""
```

While this removed the area I wanted to be deleted, it also removed the `p` element and it's content.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the thing to be removed will always be the first [text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) you can [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) that [first child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) node.

```js
const mainDiv = document.querySelector('#mainDIV');
mainDiv.removeChild(mainDiv.firstChild);
```

```html
<div id="mainDIV">Area to remove <p>Area to not remove</p></div>
```

But also watch your spelling. `mainDiv` is not `mainDIV`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content of <p> and then insert it into the inner HTML of #mainDIV, such as:

```html
document.getElementById('mainDIV').innerHTML = document.getElementById('mainDIV').querySelector('p').outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'split' function so like:

```
var your_div = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
//splits the innerHTML of the div at "<p>" and selects the inside p side
var just_the_p = your_div.innerHTML.split("<p>")[1];
your_div.innerHTML = "<p>"+just_the_p;
```

you div's innerHTML now is "Area to not remove" (plus the p tag)

also note the split will remove the start of the p tag so just add it in later

Comment: Your code won't work initially because you have the wrong id for the element. But also, probably, you shouldn't be treating HTML as a string to manipulate, but as a tree of DOM elements that have lots of methods to manipulate them.